# How to insert a scripted field using igestion pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch

So I have two fields in my docs

```
{
    emails: ["", "", ""]
    name: "",
 }
```

And I want to have a new field once the docs are indexed called uid which will just contain the concatenated strings of all the emails and the name for every doc.

I am able to get scripted field like that using this GET request on my index `_search` endpoint

```
{
 "script_fields": {
"combined": {
    "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": "def result=''; for (String email: doc['emails.keyword']) { result = result + email;} return doc['name'].value + result;"
    }
}
  }
 }
```

I want to know what my ingest pipeline PUT request body should look like if I want to have the same scripted field indexed with my docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say I have the below sample index and sample document.

### Sample Source Index

For the sake of understanding, I've created the below mapping.

```
PUT my_source_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email":{
        "type":"text"
      },
      "name":{
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Document:

```
POST my_source_index/_doc/1
{
  "email": ["john@gmail.com","doe@outlook.com"],
  "name": "johndoe"
}
```

Just follow the below steps

### Step 1: Create Ingest Pipeline

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline-concat
{
  "description" : "describe pipeline",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "join": {
        "field": "email",
        "target_field": "temp_uuid",
        "separator": "-"
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "uuid",
        "value": "{{name}}-{{temp_uuid}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "remove":{
        "field": "temp_uuid"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice that I've made use of [Ingest API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) where I am using three [processors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest-processors.html) while [creating the above pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/put-pipeline-api.html) which would be executed in sequence:

- The first processor is a [Join Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/join-processor.html), which concatenates all the email ids and creates `temp_uuid`.
- Second Processor is a [Set Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/set-processor.html), I am combining `name` with `temp_uuid`.
- And in the third step, I am removing the `temp_uuid` using [Remove Processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/remove-processor.html)

Note that I am using `-` as delimiter between all values. You can feel free to use anything you want.

### Step 2: Create Destination Index:

```
PUT my_dest_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "email":{
        "type":"text"
      },
      "name":{
        "type": "text"
      },
      "uuid":{                  <--- Do not forget to add this
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Step 3: Apply Reindex API:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my_source_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my_dest_index",
    "pipeline": "my-pipeline-concat"       <--- Make sure you add pipeline here
  } 
}
```

Note how I've mentioned the pipeline while using [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)

### Step 4: Verify Destination Index:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_dest_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "johndoe",
          "uuid" : "johndoe-john@gmail.com-doe@outlook.com",   <--- Note this
          "email" : [
            "john@gmail.com",
            "doe@outlook.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!