# Building an effective Elasticsearch query for cross_fields with fuzziness

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search, elasticsearch-query

I know that Elasticsearch does not support fuzziness with the `cross_fields` type in a `multi_match` query. I have a very difficult time with the Elasticsearch API and so I'm finding it challenging to build an analogous query that searches across multiple document fields with fuzzy string matching.

I have an index called `papers` with various fields such as `Title`, `Author.FirstName`, `Author.LastName`, `PublicationDate`, `Journal` etc... I want to be able to query with a string like "John Doe paper title 2015 journal name". `cross_fields` is the perfect `multi_match` type but it doesn't support fuzziness which is critical for my application.

Can anyone suggest a reasonable way to approach this? I've spent hours going through solutions on SO and the Elasticsearch forums with little success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) field for this scenario. Basically you are copying all the values from different fields into one new field (`my_search_field`  in the below details) and on this field, you would be able to perform fuzzy query via `fuzziness` parameter using simple [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html).

Below is how a sample mapping, document and query would be:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_fuzzy_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "my_search_field":{                    <---- Note this field
        "type": "text"
      },
      "Title":{
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "my_search_field"         <---- Note this 
      },
      "Author":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "FirstName":{
            "type":"text",
            "copy_to": "my_search_field"     <---- Note this 
          },
          "LastName":{
            "type":"text",
            "copy_to": "my_search_field"     <---- Note this 
          }
        }
      },
      "PublicationDate":{
        "type": "date",
        "copy_to": "my_search_field"        <---- Note this 
      },
      "Journal":{
        "type":"text",
        "copy_to": "my_search_field"        <---- Note this 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Document:

```
POST my_fuzzy_index/_doc/1
{
  "Title": "Fountainhead",
  "Author":[
    {
      "FirstName": "Ayn",
      "LastName": "Rand"
    }
  ],
  "PublicationDate": "2015",
  "Journal": "journal"
}
```

### Query Request:

```
POST my_fuzzy_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "my_search_field": {                                  <---- Note this field
        "query": "Aynnn Ranaad Fountainhead 2015 journal",
        "fuzziness": 3                                      <---- Fuzzy parameter
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 15,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.1027813,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_fuzzy_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.1027813,
        "_source" : {
          "Title" : "Fountainhead",
          "Author" : [
            {
              "FirstName" : "Ayn",
              "LastName" : "Rand"
            }
          ],
          "PublicationDate" : "2015",
          "Journal" : "journal"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So instead of thinking of applying fuzzy query on multiple fields, you can instead go for this approach. That way your query would be simplified.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Alternative to that would be to make use of `Span queries` as mentioned in the below link, but then again, the query would be just too complex https://stackoverflow.com/a/53409671/3838328

Comment: Ok cool, I set up a small test with `copy_to` and it seemed to work. Two quick followups: 1. Is there a straightforward way to `copy_to` an existing index? From what I gather you need to create a new index. 2. Does the order of query terms matter in this case? i.e. would 'Aynnn Ranaad' have a different score than 'Ranaad Aynnn'? Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!

Comment: 1. Existing Index nope. You need to create new index with new mapping and reindex it. In much easier way, you can make use of `Reindex API`. Just create a mapping for this new index as mentioned in this answer and execute `Step 3` after removing `pipeline` as mentioned in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60630095/3838328

Comment: 2. I don't think position of a term may not be considered while evaluating scoring and that it should give you the same score. However please test it just to be sure.