# Parsing user query with NLP to identify entities, typos and attributes and running a search on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, deep-learning, nlp, named-entity-recognition, information-retrieval

Hello StackOverflowers,

I have hundreds of thousands of documents in the following structure. I can modify the document before loading it into Elasticsearch, like adding vectors, synonyms or other annotations. Please assume that all the documents are well attributed. Attributes vary based on the category of the product.

- If there is a query, I want to show the precise product for the query.
  For example, if someone is searching for "Lee jeans" I want to show all the products which are "Jeans" from the brand "Lee".
- If the user searches for "Lee black jeans" I want to filter out by the variant "Black"
- If the user searches for "Lee spring summer jeans" then I just want to show only the following product.
- It should be capable of understanding typo's
- It should lemmatize. for example, "Chocolate milk" is "Milk", "Milk chocolate" is "Chocolate"

I've seen some of the approaches on the internet (some of the projects are outdated or not maintained anymore), but I want recommendations the developer community here on what opensource solutions which I can use and what are the changes I should make to the document before loading into Elasticsearch to achieve this.

```
{
  "product_id": 489929,
  "name_en": "Spring Summer Jeans",
  "attributes": {
    "category": "Pants",
    "type": [
      "Jeans",
      "Denim"
    ],
    "brand": "Lee",
    "material": [
      "Cotton"
    ]
  },
  "variants": {
    "size": [
      28,
      30,
      32,
      34,
      36
    ],
    "colors": [
      "Blue",
      "Black"
    ],
    "fit": [
      "Regular",
      "Narrow"
    ],
    "gender": [
      "Men",
      "Women"
    ]
  },
  "description_en": "Quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
  "variant_ids": {
    "1467547": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "7487751": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "11089927": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "11258137": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "13266321": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "13549929": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "17846649": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "22602397": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "22709931": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "23937102": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "28519361": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "31165878": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "31631591": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "36914467": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": false
    },
    "39141069": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "41416888": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "43504246": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "45374599": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "46361047": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "46909634": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "49407526": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "54529078": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "55659499": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": false
    },
    "55762371": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "57049076": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "57973674": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "58218538": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "58227462": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "58232621": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "59320783": {
      "size": 30,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "63244508": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "66194331": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "71212553": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "84143801": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "86881320": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "89177537": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "90449959": {
      "size": 36,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Narrow",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "92989653": {
      "size": 34,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "93319121": {
      "size": 32,
      "color": "Blue",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Women",
      "in_stock": true
    },
    "95212291": {
      "size": 28,
      "color": "Black",
      "fit": "Regular",
      "gender": "Men",
      "in_stock": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch don't support OOTB NLP. Recently, they have include feature in version 8 but it required license version of the Elasticsearch. Also, it seems like as of now you can use at index time only using Ingest pipeline but at query time you need to write custom wrapper which will do it. You can read my article [here](https://medium.com/@psajan106/elasticsearch-8-named-entity-recognition-ner-using-inference-ingest-pipeline-8e7bd566c5e8) on how to use at Index time.

You can use below `multi_match` query with `cross_field`with your current index mapping for **first 3 usecases** and it will give you your expected result without any NLP integration.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "Lee spring summer jeans",
      "fields": [
        "attributes.brand",
        "attributes.type",
        "variants.colors",
        "name_en"
      ],
      "operator": "and",
      "type": "cross_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

`multi_match` with cross field dont support fuzzy query and hence it will not work with above query for **usecase 4**. You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658328/building-an-effective-elasticsearch-query-for-cross-fields-with-fuzziness) answer which show how you can use `copy_to` and create one field with all values and apply fuzziness. You can add same query with `bool` clause in above one. something like below:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Lee spring summer jeans",
            "fields": [
              "attributes.brand",
              "attributes.type",
              "variants.colors",
              "name_en"
            ],
            "operator": "and",
            "type": "cross_fields"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "my_search_field": {
              "query": "Lee spring summer jeans",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Usecase 5** is not about lemmatize but it is synonyms usecase. You can configures synonyms for "Chocolate milk" is "Milk", "Milk chocolate" is "Chocolate" and all other words and apply at index time or query time using custom analyzer. You can read about synonyms [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html).